# ASP.NET Get window size in page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to resize the page based on the size of the window. I need the size of the window on the page load and when the window is being resized.

I've looked online and I found a way to do this with javascript. The problem with this is that javascript gets fired after the page_load. I know it's not possible to get javascript values before the page load, so how am I able to use the values from javascript in my code? Can I use another page that with javascript determines the size of the window, and pass it to my main page? 
I hope this is clear. Thank you!

Comment: What is your intention of getting the window size? Are you trying to call a particular method?

Comment: If it is only for a specific page within the rest of the web app, you could assign parameters within a cookie or the session before they get there that contain the width and height, then server-side before the page loads you can do something with it. Once you have initial dimensions you can use JS for any resizes after page load.

Comment: I'm trying to make a dots and boxes game that resizes according to the window. I need the window size to calculate how much space is supposed to be between each dot.

Comment: @Jake What do you mean with before they get there? Get it on another page?

Comment: @LMS Exactly. So say when they hit the homepage you create a session/cookie that stores the dimensions at that time, then they will be accessible server-side before the non-homepage is hit. After that within the page you can use something like `AHbaghen's` answer to handle users dragging and resizing after page load [jQuery .resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Based on the purpose, the alternative is to use a responsive framework, so the site doesn't care what the screen size is. It will just adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get page or windows size at server side i.e on page load function, but you will get it using client side script i.e jquery or javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() 
   {
      var w = $(window).width();
      var h = $(window).height();  
   });
</script>
```

And later on you can do your functionality when resize the window by using following function

```
window.onresize = function(event) 
{
    var height=$(window).height();
    var width=$(window).width();
    //your functionality
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. you cann't get window size from the server side. However, here is what you can do in javascript assuming you are using jQuery:

```
  var width = $(windows).width(),
      height = $(window).height();
```

After getting these values, pass them through an Ajax call to the server:

```
 $.ajax({
    method:'POST', 
    data: { w : width, h: height}, 
    // complete your ajax

 });
```